# Display Post month by month in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all post in specific category in wordpress for current month only. Means that it will display all post in this category for current month only, and then have a pagination which previous month as well as next month.

**Update on Question**
I have tried this code.
This is displaying post by month, but need a way to display this for only current month and then pagination for next previous month.

```
    <?php

$blogtime = date('Y');
$prev_limit_year = $blogtime - 1;
$prev_month = '';
$prev_year = '';

$args = array(
         'posts_per_page' => 20,
         'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
         'cat' => 1
);

$postsbymonth = new WP_Query($args);

while($postsbymonth->have_posts()) {

    $postsbymonth->the_post();

    if(get_the_time('F') != $prev_month || get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year && get_the_time('Y') == $prev_limit_year) {

                   echo "<h2>".get_the_time('F, Y')."</h2>\n\n";

        }

    ?>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                <?php // your other template tags ?>


    <?php

    $prev_month = get_the_time('F');
    $prev_year = get_the_time('Y');

}

        ?>
```

Comment: @Christophvh i have added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use like this

```
current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');

query_posts( "cat=22&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&order=ASC" );
```

If you don't need to use the $query_string variable, another method exists that is more clear and readable

```
$args = array(
    'cat'      => 22,
    'year'     => $current_year,
    'monthnum' => $current_month,
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

also check this ex.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'year' => $today['year'],
    'monthnum' => $today['mon'],
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

For details info follow this link 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Time_Parameters

**FOR PREV MONTH POST**

```
$archive_month = date('m', strtotime('1 month ago') );
$archive_year  = date('Y', strtotime('1 month ago') ); 
echo '<a href="' . get_month_link( $archive_year, $archive_month) . '">Last month\'s posts</a>';
```

post by month - follow this 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link

Comment: this was showing current month post, but not showing pagination? how could i get previous and next month link?